# Collisions between sprites in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I'm making a game in XCode using SpriteKit. The game has a player and different types of projectiles that he has to avoid. When the player collides with the projectiles, the score changes and the projectile disappears. However, when two projectiles collide, they kind of bounce away.
I want to make that every time two projectiles collide, they act like nothing happened and they keep going in their original path. What should I do?

*Note: This is not the whole code, it's just what matters.

```
    import SpriteKit

    struct Physics {
        static let player : UInt32 = 1
        static let missileOne : UInt32 = 2
        static let missileTwo : UInt32 = 3
    }

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "p1.png")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/5)
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
        player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Physics.player
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics.missileOne
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = Physics.missileTwo

        var missileOneTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnMissileOne"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        var missileTwoTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.2, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnMissileTwo"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        self.addChild(player)
    }

    //When contact happens
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.missileOne)) {

        CollisionWithMissileOne(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, missileOne: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

    } else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.player) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.missileTwo)){

        CollisionWithMissileTwo(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, missileTwo: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

    } else if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.missileOne)&&(secondBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.missileTwo)) {

        CollisionBetweenMissiles(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, missileTwo: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

        } 

    }

//For Player and MissileOne
    func CollisionWithMissileOne(player: SKSpriteNode, missileOne: SKSpriteNode) {

        missileOne.removeFromParent()
    }

//For Player and MissileTwo
    func CollisionWithMissileOne(player: SKSpriteNode, missileTwo: SKSpriteNode) {

        missileTwo.removeFromParent()
    }

//For MissileOne and MissileTwo
        func CollisionBetweenMissiles(missileOne: SKSpriteNode, missileTwo: SKSpriteNode) {

        ???WHAT SHOULD I CODE HERE???

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The confusion is that the `collisionBitMask` is used to define which physicsBodies that interacts in the physicsModel. What you really want is `contactTestBitmask`.

Also your Physics doesn't return proper values to use for a Bit Mask. As pure Ints they should be 1,2,4,8 etc.

---

Here is your code changed to something that (hopefully) works, I've commented changes wherever I've made them.

```
 struct Physics {
        static let player : UInt32 = 1
        static let missileOne : UInt32 = 2
        static let missileTwo : UInt32 = 4 // to work properly as bit masks
    }
```

This change is necessary if you want to check for contact with more than one type of physicsBody.categoryBitMask. Check out the `player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ...` in didMoveToView:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    // All your existing player-stuff is fine until...
    // contactTest, not collision but contact, also: use bitwise OR
    player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Physics.missileOne | Physics.missileTwo
    self.addChild(player)

    // It is not recommended to use NSTimer for SpriteKit, use SKActions instead
    let missileOneWait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
    let callSpawnOneAction = SKAction.runBlock({ self.spawnMissileOne() })
    let missileOneRepeat = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([missileOneWait, callSpawnOneAction]))
    runAction(missileOneRepeat)

    let missileTwoWait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.2)
    let callSpawnTwoAction = SKAction.runBlock({ self.spawnMissileTwo() })
    let missileTwoRepeat = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([missileTwoWait, callSpawnTwoAction]))
    runAction(missileTwoRepeat)
}
```

Pretty much rewritten didBeginContact to something I believe reads and *scales* a lot better:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = contact.bodyA
    var secondBody = contact.bodyB

    // Rewritten with dynamic variables
    var playerNode : SKSpriteNode? {
        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.player {
            return firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode
        } else if secondBody.categoryBitMask == Physics.player {
            return secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode
        }
        return nil
    }

    // If you want to handle contact between missiles you need to split this 
    // into two different variables
    var missileNode : SKSpriteNode? {
        let bitmask1 = firstBody.categoryBitMask
        let bitmask2 = secondBody.categoryBitMask

        if bitmask1 == Physics.missileOne || bitmask1 == Physics.missileTwo {
            return firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode
        } else if bitmask2 == Physics.missileOne || bitmask2 == Physics.missileTwo {
            return secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode
        }
        return nil
    }

    if playerNode != nil {
        collisionBetweenPlayer(playerNode, missile: missileNode)
    }
}
```

Then you'll only need one function for contact between missile and player:

```
func collisionBetweenPlayer(player: SKSpriteNode?, missile: SKSpriteNode?) {
    missile?.removeFromParent()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it changes everything! Could you (or somebody else) please explain to me how to make the two missiles pass through each other without collision?

Comment: It doesn't really change everything, you can still keep your didBeginContact function as it is for instance. If you don't want to use my suggestions, that's fine, but you still need to use contactBitMask instead of collisionBitMask. For your question, it's easy: `missileSprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0`

Comment: So the only things you _need_ to take away from my answer is to use `contact` instead of `collisionBitMasks` to check for (what you refer to) as collisions. Also the BitMasks, need to have proper BitMask values (1,2,4,8) etc. in order to to work properly with the BitWise OR...

Comment: I followed every instruction, this does not prevents both missiles from colliding with each other and "bouncing". I'm sorry for the delay, but thanks for the tip about Contact

Comment: If you set the collissionBitmasks to 0 for BITH your missile spriteNodes.physicsBodies it should be impossible for them to interact (bounce) off each other. I haven't seen the code where you set up these sprites though so it's a bit hard to break down where the problem lies.

Comment: If i set the bitmask of both missiles as the same, xcode does not recognize which missile is being hit by the player. I want to have different actions depending on which missile is hit.

Comment: They should have different categoryBitmasks but both should have 0 for their collisionBitmask. You need to sort out the differences between category-, contact-, and collision-bitmasks...